# Can't activate administrator approved form to a site collection. List Item Validation Error

Tags: custom-form, central-administration

When I try to activate any form to a specific site collection, I get List Item Validation Failed error. If I change the site collection to a different one it works. The error occurs even when I try to activate a blank form to our production site collection.

Relevant lines from the logs:

```
10/12/2012 05:24:15.79  w3wp.exe (0x1F1C)                           0x2CF8  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (POST:http://machinename:39140/_admin/ActivateFormTemplate.aspx?templateId=bcc265b4-6dee-41d6-8e03-0f06519686c2)   a559efbd-2917-4a41-8614-87eda9f4aca1
10/12/2012 05:24:15.79  w3wp.exe (0x1F1C)                           0x2CF8  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Site=/  a559efbd-2917-4a41-8614-87eda9f4aca1
10/12/2012 05:24:15.80  w3wp.exe (0x1F1C)                           0x2CF8  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    High        Leaving Monitored Scope (PostAuthenticateRequestHandler). Execution Time=4.23685133166366   a559efbd-2917-4a41-8614-87eda9f4aca1
10/12/2012 05:24:15.81  w3wp.exe (0x1F1C)                           0x2CF8  SharePoint Foundation           SPRequest                       8e3n    Medium      token timestamp is in the future. probably machine clock out of sync    a559efbd-2917-4a41-8614-87eda9f4aca1
10/12/2012 05:24:15.82  w3wp.exe (0x1F1C)                           0x2CF8  SharePoint Foundation           SPRequest                       8e3n    Medium      token timestamp is in the future. probably machine clock out of sync    a559efbd-2917-4a41-8614-87eda9f4aca1
10/12/2012 05:24:15.83  w3wp.exe (0x1F1C)                           0x2CF8  SharePoint Foundation           SPRequest                       8e3n    Medium      token timestamp is in the future. probably machine clock out of sync    a559efbd-2917-4a41-8614-87eda9f4aca1
10/12/2012 05:24:15.84  w3wp.exe (0x1F1C)                           0x2CF8  InfoPath Forms Services         Conversion and Deployment       145t    Medium      FormTemplate.Activate - starting for FormTemplate urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:crbpublish4:-myXSD-2012-10-05T18-29-01 (crbpublish4.xsn) on site: http://machinename:7010   a559efbd-2917-4a41-8614-87eda9f4aca1
10/12/2012 05:24:15.84  w3wp.exe (0x1F1C)                           0x2CF8  SharePoint Foundation           General                         88jb    Medium      Feature Activation: Activating Feature 'FT-01-830186cb-0014-e02f-5550-fff023812426' (ID: '830186cb-0014-e02f-5550-fff023812426') at URL http://machinename:7010.    a559efbd-2917-4a41-8614-87eda9f4aca1
10/12/2012 05:24:15.87  w3wp.exe (0x1F1C)                           0x2CF8  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8yrn    Medium      Instantiating module "XSN": File could not be added at URL "solution.xsn": Error 290629024  a559efbd-2917-4a41-8614-87eda9f4aca1
10/12/2012 05:24:15.87  w3wp.exe (0x1F1C)                           0x2CF8  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8kh7    High        List Item Validation Failed.    a559efbd-2917-4a41-8614-87eda9f4aca1
10/12/2012 05:24:15.87  w3wp.exe (0x1F1C)                           0x2CF8  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8e2r    Medium      Possible mismatch between the reported error with code = 0x81079801 and message: "List Item Validation Failed." and the returned error with code 0x810200c6.    a559efbd-2917-4a41-8614-87eda9f4aca1
10/12/2012 05:24:15.87  w3wp.exe (0x1F1C)                           0x2CF8  SharePoint Foundation           Feature Infrastructure          889y    High        The element of type 'Module' for feature 'FT-01-830186cb-0014-e02f-5550-fff023812426' (id: 830186cb-0014-e02f-5550-fff023812426) threw an exception during activation: List Item Validation Failed. a559efbd-2917-4a41-8614-87eda9f4aca1
10/12/2012 05:24:15.87  w3wp.exe (0x1F1C)                           0x2CF8  SharePoint Foundation           General                         72by    High        Feature Activation: Threw an exception, attempting to roll back.  Feature 'FT-01-830186cb-0014-e02f-5550-fff023812426' (ID: '830186cb-0014-e02f-5550-fff023812426').  Exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: List Item Validation Failed. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x810200C6): List Item Validation Failed.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.EnableModuleFromXml(String bstrSetupDirectory, String bstrFeatureDirectory, String bstrUrl, String bstrXML, Boolean fForceUnghost, ISPEnableModuleCallback pModuleContext)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.EnableModuleFromXml(String bstrSetupDirectory, String bstrFeatureDirectory, String bstrUrl, String bstrXML, Boolean fForceUnghost, ISPEnableModuleCallback pModuleContext)     --- End of inner ... a559efbd-2917-4a41-8614-87eda9f4aca1
10/12/2012 05:24:15.87* w3wp.exe (0x1F1C)                           0x2CF8  SharePoint Foundation           General                         72by    High        ...exception stack trace ---     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPElementDefinitionCollection.ProvisionModules(SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPSite site, SPWeb web, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPElementDefinitionCollection.ProvisionElements(SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPWebApplication webapp, SPSite site, SPWeb web, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.Activate(SPSite siteParent, SPWeb webParent, SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)    a559efbd-2917-4a41-8614-87eda9f4aca1
10/12/2012 05:24:15.87  w3wp.exe (0x1F1C)                           0x2CF8  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    High        Leaving Monitored Scope (Feature Activation: Activating Feature 'FT-01-830186cb-0014-e02f-5550-fff023812426' (ID: '830186cb-0014-e02f-5550-fff023812426') at URL http://machinename:7010.). Execution Time=31.1557753848604 a559efbd-2917-4a41-8614-87eda9f4aca1
10/12/2012 05:24:15.87  w3wp.exe (0x1F1C)                           0x2CF8  InfoPath Forms Services         Conversion and Deployment       82en    Exception   Activation failure Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: List Item Validation Failed. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x810200C6): List Item Validation Failed.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.EnableModuleFromXml(String bstrSetupDirectory, String bstrFeatureDirectory, String bstrUrl, String bstrXML, Boolean fForceUnghost, ISPEnableModuleCallback pModuleContext)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.EnableModuleFromXml(String bstrSetupDirectory, String bstrFeatureDirectory, String bstrUrl, String bstrXML, Boolean fForceUnghost, ISPEnableModuleCallback pModuleContext)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPElementDefinitionCollection.ProvisionModules(SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPSite ... a559efbd-2917-4a41-8614-87eda9f4aca1
10/12/2012 05:24:15.87* w3wp.exe (0x1F1C)                           0x2CF8  InfoPath Forms Services         Conversion and Deployment       82en    Exception   ...site, SPWeb web, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPElementDefinitionCollection.ProvisionElements(SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPWebApplication webapp, SPSite site, SPWeb web, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.Activate(SPSite siteParent, SPWeb webParent, SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternal(SPFeatureDefinition featdef, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternalWithName(Guid featureId, String featureName, Versio...  a559efbd-2917-4a41-8614-87eda9f4aca1
10/12/2012 05:24:15.87* w3wp.exe (0x1F1C)                           0x2CF8  InfoPath Forms Services         Conversion and Deployment       82en    Exception   ...n version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly, SPFeatureDefinitionScope featdefScope)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.Add(Guid featureId)     at Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server.Administration.FormTemplate.Activate(SPSite site)     at Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server.ApplicationPages.ActivateFormTemplatePage.<>c__DisplayClass6.<ActivateFormOnSite>b__0()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Diagnostics.FirstChanceHandler.ExceptionFilter(Boolean fRethrowException, TryBlock tryBlock, FilterBlock filter, CatchBlock catchBlock, FinallyBlock finallyBlock)    a559efbd-2917-4a41-8614-87eda9f4aca1
10/12/2012 05:24:15.87  w3wp.exe (0x1F1C)                           0x2CF8  SharePoint Server               Unified Logging Service         c91s    Monitorable Watson bucket parameters: SharePoint Server 2010, ULSException14, 41b7c39f "infopath forms services", 0e00129b "14.0.4763.0", 1f65804a "microsoft.sharepoint", 0e0017eb "14.0.6123.0", 4fd15297 "thu jun 07 18:17:11 2012", 00000a72 "00000a72", 0000014e "0000014e", 5dedbedb "spexception:810200c6", 3832656e "82en"  a559efbd-2917-4a41-8614-87eda9f4aca1
10/12/2012 05:24:15.87  w3wp.exe (0x1F1C)                           0x2CF8  SharePoint Server               Unified Logging Service         b6ig    Medium      Not reporting 82en to Watson because it is not enabled  a559efbd-2917-4a41-8614-87eda9f4aca1
10/12/2012 05:24:15.87  w3wp.exe (0x1F1C)                           0x2CF8  InfoPath Forms Services         Administration                  82eq    Warning     Activation of form template on site collection http://machinename:7010 failed. (User: SYMANTEC\Administrator, Form Name: crbpublish4, IP: , Request: http://machinename:39140/_admin/ActivateFormTemplate.aspx?templateId=bcc265b4-6dee-41d6-8e03-0f06519686c2, Form ID: urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:crbpublish4:-myXSD-2012-10-05T18-29-01, Type: SPException, Exception Message: List Item Validation Failed. List Item Validation Failed.) a559efbd-2917-4a41-8614-87eda9f4aca1
10/12/2012 05:24:15.88  w3wp.exe (0x1F1C)                           0x2CF8  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: List Item Validation Failed.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.EnableModuleFromXml(String bstrSetupDirectory, String bstrFeatureDirectory, String bstrUrl, String bstrXML, Boolean fForceUnghost, ISPEnableModuleCallback pModuleContext)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.EnableModuleFromXml(String bstrSetupDirectory, String bstrFeatureDirectory, String bstrUrl, String bstrXML, Boolean fForceUnghost, ISPEnableModuleCallback pModuleContext) a559efbd-2917-4a41-8614-87eda9f4aca1
10/12/2012 05:24:15.88  w3wp.exe (0x1F1C)                           0x2CF8  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (POST:http://machinename:39140/_admin/ActivateFormTemplate.aspx?templateId=bcc265b4-6dee-41d6-8e03-0f06519686c2)). Execution Time=86.5597443250469 a559efbd-2917-4a41-8614-87eda9f4aca1
```

Comment: a559efbd-2917-4a41-8614-87eda9f4aca1 What is this guid related to in your deployment? Also the error is related to a SP2010 hotfix http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2405789

Comment: Is there any validation settings in your list? Does the site collection which is working resides in the same Content DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to duplicate your log messages nearly exactly (other than the clock sync error) by turning on validation in the Form Templates library in my test site collection, setting a rule which is guaranteed to fail (such as =[Form Description]="A"), and then attempting to activate a template to the site collection in which that library resides.

Go to `http://machinename:7010/FormServerTemplates` and check for/remove any validation settings in that list, and then try to activate your template to that site collection again. I can't imagine any reason you'd want to set validation on that library, but if it's intentional, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: There was no good reason... there was no reason at all.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of the error seems to be (as you may guess) problem with list validation on a document library.

While I have never seen this error in this instance, I would inspect validation applied to the document library 'Form Templates' and see if there are any differences between the site collection that works, and the site collection that does not. Remember that when you activate a administrator-approved xsn, SharePoint is creating an instance of that template in the 'Form Templates' library - so if there are any problems during that process it may explain why you would see such obscure errors.

Demo of list validation settings that may help

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b4DKJxanK7s

Hope that helps and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the validation on document library, as you are trying to activate a blank form.

please follow this article, they are discussing the same kind of issue

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/b25febd3-003a-4ffe-aea9-09293fd0f722

In that there is another work around for validation, as well as link to the hotfix is given.

Try both the ways.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check if there are any validation given on document library columns like numeric check or enforce unique values. This could cause this type of error. I don't see any other reason as per your log given.